# Grep for mismatched values in a line

Tags: grep

I have a Kubernetes cluster with lots of pods. Each pod has an arbitrary number of containers. From the command line I can list all the pods and get an output like:

```
pod1  2/2
pod2  1/3
pod3  1/2
pod4  4/5
pod5  5/5
pod5  0/1
...etc...
```

I want a grep that would show me the pods that have containers that have not started yet. i.e. List all `podN x/y` where `x!=y`.  The closest I have got is:

`kubectl get pods | grep -e "1/[^1]" -e "2/[^2]" -e "3/[^3]" -e "4/[^4]" -e "5/[^5]"`

This works but I'm hoping there is a way in grep (or other Linux CLI tools) I could do this without the endless -e terms e.g. by assigning the match to a variable

`kubectl get pods | grep "${var=[0-9]+}/[^${var}]"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppresses all lines with identical numbers with grep:

```
kubectl get pods | grep -vE '([0-9]+)/\1'
```

or

```
kubectl get pods | awk -F ' +|/' '$2!=$3'
```

or

```
kubectl get pods | sed -E '/([0-9]+)\/\1/d'
```

Output:

```
pod2  1/3
pod3  1/2
pod4  4/5
pod5  0/1
```